# If 'userExists' = true then it is running both bits of code

Tags: java, android-asynctask

I have this section of code which sends data to web services and into a SQL database. At the moment when the variable is set to true, it executes both bits of code when it should only execute one section. I have tried numerous different methods and debugging it thoroughly but I cannot seem to find a solution to this problem.

```
        if (playerExists) 
    {
        //Update record where equal to username and change the field 'score'
        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String name = playerName;

                newScore = Integer.toString(existScore + Integer.parseInt(score));

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("score", newScore));

                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(updateURL);

                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                return "Score Submitted.";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
            {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Score Submitted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        SendPostReqAsyncTask AsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        AsyncTask.execute(playerName, newScore);
    } else {
        //Just insert score into table
        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String name = playerName;

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("score", score));

                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(insertURL);

                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                return "Score Submitted.";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result)
            {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Score Submitted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        SendPostReqAsyncTask AsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        AsyncTask.execute(playerName, score);
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps one branch is executed while the variable is `false` and then the other branch is executed when the variable is set `true` while the task initiated by the first branch is still running asynchronously. Could that be what you are observing?

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, can you 'kill' a Asynctask?

Comment: You can't just kill the task. You can call [`cancel(boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) on the task. That may or may not stop the background task itself (depending on how you implement `doInBackground(Object[])`) but it will cause `onCancelled(Object)` to be called instead of `onPostExecute(Object)` once `doInBackground(Object[])` returns.

Comment: So what would have to go in the 'onCancelled(Object)'

Comment: Whatever you want to deal with a cancelled task after it's finished, nor nothing at all if you don't need to do anything. Typically one might pop up a notification to the user that the task was cancelled.